# JSP excute doPost in the first visit

Tags: java, jsp

I maked JSP page with a form. User can write a comment, it will be send with POST method. The servlet will store it in the datastore and make a list of all the comments and forward it to the jsp and the jsp will put them in a table. The problem is that in the first visit nothing will be there because doPOst is not called ! this is my code

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        // INSERT CODE HERE

        System.out.println("received HTTP POST");
        String postContent = request.getParameter("post_text");
        System.out.println(postContent);
         Date date= new Date();
      Timestamp timeStamp=  new Timestamp(date.getTime());
     long lonTime= timeStamp.getTime();

            DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();       
            Entity post = new Entity("post");
            post.setProperty("content", postContent);

            post.setProperty("time", lonTime); 
            datastore.put(post);
        System.out.println(    post.getKey()   );

        int pageSize = 20;
        FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(pageSize);

        Query q = new Query("post").addSort("time", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
        PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

        QueryResultList<Entity> results = pq.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        for (Entity entity : results) {

 System.out.println(entity.getProperty ("content"));
 System.out.println(entity.getProperty ("time"));
        }

        request.setAttribute("postList",results);
        String strViewPage="/tublr.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(strViewPage);
        if (dispatcher != null){
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } ;
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this. You could add a servlet that handles the initial request (instead of your JSP). It can handle retrieval of the comments and direct your output to a JSP where you display them. When you submit (to the above servlet) you can continue directing to the same JSP. This is only one option. You are really looking at the MVC pattern.

Comment: Why cant you show 'No Comments available' when you load the JSP? so when the user login first he/she will get no comment available message. IF the user submit then you can show the message. This code should be in .jsp page.